# Entity Framework Stored Procedures - Multiple Result sets with CodeFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using the below code to get a regular result from a stored procedure:

```
var paramUserId = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "userId",
    Value = userId
};

string query = string.Format("{0} {1}",
              "SpSetFoo",
              "@userId");

var results = context.Database.SqlQuery<FooModel>(query,
                                             paramUserId);

result = results.ToList();
```

Meanwhile I need to retrieve multiple result sets from another stored procedure, which I found it's possible according to this documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

However the example from Microsoft is using ADO.NET. It's not possible to achieve the same result without ADO.NET using EF instead?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to call a stored procedure which gives two result sets in EF?

Comment: Exactly, two result sets. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can use Entity Framework. What version of the .net framework are you using?

Comment: @sarin I am using EF 6.1, the latest I believe. thanks

Comment: @hugo.hilario .net framework not EntityFramework! Version 4.5?

Comment: Yes precisely. Thanks

Comment: [Get multiple result set in a single call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48614259/3110834).

Answer (score 17):

See this link. this will work with EF 6.0 Code first.

http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-6-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedures

I've My own extension based on the above link, C# 6.0 , add parameter and work with multiple select not necessary a procedure.

```
 public static class MultipleResultSets
{

    #region Public Methods
    public static MultipleResultSetWrapper MultipleResults(this DbContext db,string query,IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters=null) => new MultipleResultSetWrapper(db: db,query: query,parameters: parameters);
    #endregion Public Methods

    #region Public Classes
    public class MultipleResultSetWrapper
    {

        #region Public Fields
        public List<Func<DbDataReader,IEnumerable>> _resultSets;
        #endregion Public Fields

        #region Private Fields
        private readonly IObjectContextAdapter _Adapter;
        private readonly string _CommandText;
        private readonly DbContext _db;
        private readonly IEnumerable<SqlParameter> _parameters;
        #endregion Private Fields

        #region Public Constructors
        public MultipleResultSetWrapper(DbContext db,string query,IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
        {
            _db = db;
            _Adapter = db;
            _CommandText = query;
            _parameters = parameters;
            _resultSets = new List<Func<DbDataReader,IEnumerable>>();
        }
        #endregion Public Constructors

        #region Public Methods
        public MultipleResultSetWrapper AddResult<TResult>()
        {
            _resultSets.Add(OneResult<TResult>);
            return this;
        }

        public List<IEnumerable> Execute()
        {
            var results = new List<IEnumerable>();

            using(var connection = _db.Database.Connection)
            {
                connection.Open();
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = _CommandText;
                if(_parameters?.Any() ?? false) { command.Parameters.AddRange(_parameters.ToArray()); }
                using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    foreach(var resultSet in _resultSets)
                    {
                        results.Add(resultSet(reader));
                    }
                }

                return results;
            }
        }
        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Private Methods
        private IEnumerable OneResult<TResult>(DbDataReader reader)
        {
            var result = _Adapter
                .ObjectContext
                .Translate<TResult>(reader)
                .ToArray();
            reader.NextResult();
            return result;
        }
        #endregion Private Methods

    }
    #endregion Public Classes

}
```

and this is an example how to call it

```
var Policy = "123";
var Results=   db
        .MultipleResults($"EXEC GetPolicyInfo '{Policy}'")
        .AddResult<Driver>()
        .AddResult<Address>()
        .AddResult<Phone>()
        .AddResult<Email>()
        .AddResult<Vehicle>()
        .Execute();
        var Output= new clsPolicyInfo
        {
            Drivers = Results[0] as Driver[],
            Addresses = Results[1] as Address[],
            Phones = Results[2] as Phone[],
            Emails = Results[3] as Email[],
            Vehicles = Results[4] as Vehicle[]
        };
```

Comment: i tried your code, when i try to query, i am getting error as `Additional information: Cannot drop database "<databasename>" because it is currently in use.` Why it is trying to drop the database?
Click below link for error message:
> https://www.screencast.com/t/psYjKkM5SWK 

Any suggestion really helps.

Thank you

Comment: @jks Try first to run simple select statement, So if your procedure return multiple result Comment all the rest and Keep the first one.
Usually your error is related to the DbContext Setup in the construct of your class

Comment: I liked the modified version that someone commented in that link:
https://github.com/Icey88/RandomCodeSamples/tree/master/MultipleResultSets, which directly receives a `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Due to the `using(var connection = _db.Database.Connection)`, the `DbContext` you pass to this class cannot be used after calling `Execute`.

Comment: @Andrew, I think that you have dispose the DBContext before you got your output

Comment: I think the `using` in `Execute` does that. I wanted to use my existing connection just after calling `Execute` and it failed. I moved my code before the call to `Execute` and it worked just fine. I changed your code to just do `connection.Open()` and `connection.Close()` (in a `try-finally`) and that fixed the issue. Basically, your `using` calls `connection.Dispose()` at the end and that's what caused the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to pass "A member of the type, 'CreatedOn', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name." I used the model created by entity framework which have extra columns that i don't return from the SP. Can't they be nulled in this case instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: @Ali123 Just add the column in the database with a default value Getdate() no need to Added to the model

Answer (score 10):

This is an old topic but adding comments here just in case someone needs it. I needed to consume a stored proc that returned two tables from a different database and then after processing the returned data storing into our application database. Referred to the standard documentation and followed the steps but did not like it. First there were problems and the code exposed some underbelly that was not a good idea from maintainability point of view.

That where a Nuget package designed specifically for handling SPs come into picture. Take a look at [CodeFirstStoredProcs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeFirstStoredProcs/). Brilliant package with very specific focus and does the job perfectly. This returns a collection of objects for each result set of stored proc that can then be used any way desired. Their is a good and consistent support for different versions of EF including version 6. Also check the explanation on code project [Code First Stored Procedures](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures). Downloaded source code even has a PDF that explains how to use it in detailed steps.

Big thanks to the author aureolin.

Answer (score 2):

> However the example from Microsoft is using ADO.NET. It's not possible
>   to achieve the same result without ADO.NET using EF instead?

**Entity Framework is part of ADO.NET**... [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets) that you have linked, is showing you what you want using ADO.NET Entity Framework. The example is using raw sql command to execute a stored procedure (there is no point writing a LINQ query if you have already written your SQL procedure). [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa697427(v=vs.80)):

> A primary goal of the upcoming version of ADO.NET is to raise the
>   level of abstraction for data programming, thus helping to eliminate
>   the impedance mismatch between data models and between languages that
>   application developers would otherwise have to deal with. Two
>   innovations that make this move possible are **Language-Integrated Query**
>   and the **ADO.NET Entity Framework**. The Entity Framework exists as a new
>   part of the ADO.NET family of technologies. ADO.NET will LINQ-enable
>   many data access components: LINQ to SQL, LINQ to DataSet and LINQ to
>   Entities.

---

### The code:

It's not clear what are the result sets that you are returning from your procedure: `SpSetFoo`... the name `SpSetFoo` suggests that procedure updates Foo in the DB. To simplify things, I assume you have a procedure called `GetFooAndBarForUser`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFooAndBarForUser] (@userId int)
AS
    SELECT * FROM Foo F WHERE F.UserId = @userId
    SELECT * FROM Bar B WHERE B.UserId = @userId
```

This is how you can read both models:

```
public void GetTwoResultSetsForUserId(int userId)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        // Create a SQL command and add parameter
        var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetFooAndBarForUser]";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userId", userId));

        // execute your command
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Read first model --> Foo
        var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext
            .Translate<Foo>(reader, "Foo", MergeOption.AppendOnly);

        // move to next result set
        reader.NextResult();

        // Read second model --> Bar
        var bar = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext
            .Translate<Post>(reader, "Bar", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
    }
}
```