# Avoid multiple calls to database with C# & EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a requirement where I need to display a value based on Id. For that, I am making multiple calls to the database, to different tables. Is it possible to reduce the number of calls?

I have switch conditions based on which call to DB occurs. Below is sample

```
foreach (var items in table1)
{
    foreach (var item in items.List)
    {
         switch (item.condition)
         {
             case condition1:
             case condition2:
                 item.nvalue= string.Join(",", _context.table1.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.Title));
                 break;

             case condition3:
                 item.nvalue= string.Join(",", _context.tabl2.Where(x => secondIds.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.newvalu));
                 break;

             case condition4:
                 item.nvalue= string.Join(",", _context.tabl3.Where(x => someIds.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.oldvalue));
                 break;

             case condition5:
                 item.nvalue= string.Join(",", _context.tabl4.Where(x=>textIds.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.note));
                 break;

             default:
                 item.nvalue= "";
                 break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: that seems like a code smell...

Comment: Did you tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172888/entity-framework-stored-procedures-multiple-result-sets-with-codefirst This is applicable for EF core also.

Comment: It might be possible, but depends. (1) what is the EF Core version? (2) what is the type of `table1` variable here `foreach (var items in table1)` - in-memory collection or db `IQueryable<>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce number of calls you can at least group your items by condition:

```
var groups = table1
    .SelectMany(t => t.List)
    .GroupBy(i => switch (i.condition)
     {
         case condition1:
         case condition2: 
             return 1;
         case condition3:
             return 2;
         ......
         default: return 0;
     });
foreach(var group in groups)
{
     string nvalue;
     switch (g.Key)
     {
         case 1:
             nvalue = string.Join(",", _context.table1.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.Title));
             break;

         case 2:
             nvalue = string.Join(",", _context.tabl2.Where(x => secondIds.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.newvalu));
             break;
         .....
         default:
             nvalue= string.Empty;
             break;
     }
     foreach(vat item in group)
     {
         item.nvalue = nvalue;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce your database calls, and if your tables are not too large or they are fundamental tables, you can cache the tables in the memory with Caching Data.
Full Documentation is over here: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications) or [Working with Cache](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/working-with-caching-in-C-Sharp/)

I hope it will help you to solve your problem. Good luck.